# make a url accessible from one job to another on circleci

Tags: docker, testing, automated-tests, circleci, testcafe

I have two jobs, 'build' and 'test'. 'build' job builds and runs the docker image. I'm able to access the url http://0.0.0.0:3000 to run my tests from the same job. But when I run my tests from 'test' job, it doesn't recognize http://0.0.0.0:3000.

```
jobs:
  build:
    .
    .<other code>
    .
    steps:
      - run:
          docker build . -t company/project:${CIRCLE_SHA1}
          docker run --net=host -e DOPPLER_TOKEN=${DOPPLER_TOKEN} -d company/project:${CIRCLE_SHA1} "npm run dev"
          docker run --net=host -v ~/projects/project_name/tests/:/tests -v ~/projects/project_name/node_modules/:/node_modules -it testcafe/testcafe chromium:headless
```

The above code seems to run perfectly fine.

```
jobs:
  build:
    .
    .<other code>
    .
    steps:
      - run:
          docker build . -t company/project:${CIRCLE_SHA1}
          docker run --net=host -e DOPPLER_TOKEN=${DOPPLER_TOKEN} -d company/project:${CIRCLE_SHA1} "npm run dev"
  test:
    working_directory: ~/projects/project_name
    machine: true
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          docker run --net=host -v ~/projects/project_name/tests/:/tests -v ~/projects/project_name/node_modules/:/node_modules -it testcafe/testcafe chromium:headless
```

This doesn't work. It gives an error

`A request to "http://0.0.0.0:3000" has failed. You can find troubleshooting information for this issue at "https://go.devexpress.com/TestCafe_FAQ_ARequestHasFailed.aspx". Error details: Failed to find a DNS-record for the resource at "http://0.0.0.0:3000"`

I've also tried the curl command to access the url and it gives an error
`curl -o - http://0.0.0.0:3000 curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 3000: Connection refused`

Any help regarding this would be very helpful.

Comment: It seems that your application runs inside the first container and it is not visible outside of the container. You need to publish the 3000 port to make it accessible for tests (check [https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/) for details)

Comment: @Shurygin.Sergey Thank you. I tried it, but it didn't work. Looks like circle doesn't support it as of now.